# Maximum Number of Applications can be Registered in azure b2c active directory?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

What is the maximum number of Applications Registered in Azure B2C active Directory? Is there any limitations? With this I just wanted to understand for how many applications I can provide single Sign on(SSO) for my B2C Users.

Answer (score 0):

An admin creating 10,000 applications should not be an issue here.  There is a non-changeable limit of 250 objects created by a non-admin.